# Convert multiple hex values to decimal separated by commas

Tags: c#, linq, integer, hex, decimal

I am doing an analysis of a csv file that has multiple columns and rows.

I am pulling specific data from the csv file and importing the data into 
a datagridview. I would like to pull data from a column with multiple hex values (separated by commas) on each row and convert all the values from hex to integers and place them into the datagridview. The problem I am having is I don't know how to convert all the values from hex to integer and place them in datagridview. I am only able to convert the first Value and place that single value into the datagridview. ex (500)

If I do not convert any values I am able to place all the values from a column's row into the datagridview. ex (1F4,96,3D4,14A)

```
// converting the first value on each row and placing to datagridview
rawData = line.Split('"')[5];
firstValData = rawData.Split(',').First();
int datatoHex = Convert.ToInt32(firstValData, 16);
allRow["Data"] = datatoHex;

Construct.MainDataTable.Rows.Add(allRow);
dataGridView1.DataSource = Construct.MainDataTable;

//I attempted to do this but doesnt work
rawData = line.Split('"')[5];
allValData = rawData.Split(',').All();
int datatoHex = Convert.ToInt32(allValData, 16);
allRow["Data"] = datatoHex;

Construct.MainDataTable.Rows.Add(allRow);
dataGridView1.DataSource = Construct.MainDataTable;
```

Comment: You'll need to use a loop to go through each value in `allValData` and add each as a new row in your table.

Comment: Use following : int number = int.Parse("1F4", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);  For multiple numbers :  int[] numbers = "1F4,96,3D4,14A".Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(x => int.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
rawData = line.Split('"')[5];
var valDatas = rawData.Split(',').Select(s=> Convert.ToInt32(s, 16));

foreach(int val in valDatas)
{
   //whatever you want to do 
}
```